# Pythonで文字列から日付の型へ変更したい

Tags: python, python3

下記のコードを使って
テキストの文字列から日付の型へ変更したいですが、
別の日付のフォーマットになってしまいます。
同じ日付のフォーマットにするにはどのようにすれば良いでしょうか。

**実現したい内容**
テキストの文字列をエクセルへ保存し、
文字列から日付の型へ変更したいです。

テキスト

```
国,日付
アメリカ,22/6/21
,2022/7/1
,2022/8/6
,22/4/29
カナダ,2022/7/5
```

**実現したい結果**

```
国,日付
アメリカ,2022/6/21
,2022/7/1
,2022/8/6
,2022/4/29
カナダ,2022/7/5

国      object
日付    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

**現在の処理**

```
国,日付
アメリカ,2021-06-22 00:00:00
,2022-07-01 00:00:00
,2022-08-06 00:00:00
,2029-04-22 00:00:00
カナダ,2022-07-05 00:00:00

国      object
日付    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

どのように日付型に変更すれば良いでしょうか。
ご教授の程お願いします。

コード

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt, date, timedelta


input_folder=r"C:\Users\user\Documents\excel\test.txt"
output_folder=r"C:\Users\user\Documents\excel\test1.xlsx"

df = pd.read_table(input_folder,encoding='utf_8',sep=',')
#print(df.dtypes)

#指定のフォーマットで文字列
df['日付']=pd.to_datetime(df['日付']).dt.strftime("%Y/%#m/%#d").fillna('')
print(df.dtypes)

#指定のフォーマットで日付型
df['日付'] = pd.to_datetime(df["日付"],format="%Y/%m/%d")
print(df.dtypes)

df.to_excel(output_folder,encoding='utf_8_sig',index=False)
```

Comment: `df['日付'] = pd.to_datetime(df['日付']).dt.date.fillna('')`

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。上記の方法でやってみましたが、日付ではなく書式はユーザー定義になっておりました。また`2022/6/21`→`2021/06/22`、`2022/4/29`→`2029/4/22`になってしまいます。

Comment: 日付を`datetime64[ns]`に変更したいですが、可能でしょうか。もし分かりましたら、教えていただける嬉しいです。

Answer (score 1):

`pd.ExcelWriter`の引数`date_format`および`datetime_format`に書式を設定すれば良いかと思います。

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("test2.xlsx", date_format="YYYY/MM/DD", datetime_format="YYYY/MM/DD") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer)
```

[pandas.ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas-excelwriter)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。上記の方法でやってみましたが、日付ではなく標準の書式になっておりました。

Comment: 日付を`datetime64[ns]`に変更したいですが、可能でしょうか。もし分かりましたら、教えていただける嬉しいです。

Comment: pandas 1.4.2、Excel2021の組み合わせでは「ユーザー定義のyyyy/mm/dd」になっています。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。日付を`datetime64[ns]`に変更したいですが、厳しいでしょうか。